# File uploads and max_execution_time and request_terminate_timeout

Tags: php, nginx, http

In case of HTTP file uploads (nginx+php5-fpm) does `max_execution_time` (in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`) or `request_terminate_timeout` (in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`) also include the time the file took to upload?